# Using 'gloo' backend with Huggingface Accelerate

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I installed the huggingface `Accelerate` library to train the BERT model in multiple GPUs. I installed the `Accelerate` library using `pip` in the `Anaconda` environment. But I couldnt the `accelerate` command in powershell.

The following `accelerate` command

```
accelerate config
```

throws the following error:

```
accelerate : The term 'accelerate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ accelerate config
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (accelerate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I used the example mentioned in their [GitHub Page](https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate/blob/main/examples/nlp_example.py). As the `accelerate` command was not working from poershell, I used the `torch.distributed.launch` to run the script as follows:

```
 python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node 1 --use_env ./nlp_example.py
```

Since I was using Windows OS, it gave the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Distributed package doesn't have NCCL built in
```

My doubt is, will it to possible to change the backend to use `gloo`, rather than 'NCCL' in `Accelerate` package?

Kindly help. Thank you.